# Oracle OSB Proxy service Error

Tags: oracle, jms, osb, oracle-aq

I have created a jms consuming proxy service with queue created using Oracle AQ. And the proxy service is routed to Business service which enqueues same message into different queue created using orace AQ.
Proxy service is running fine and the message is put in to destination queue, but its throwing error message as below

***unexpected failure while processing an incoming message for endpoint proxy service***

and I think because of the erorr, the service is retrying again and the message is posted to destination queue 16 times.

Please help me in resolving this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with the transaction in the Proxy service or the JMS retries. It could be the Global transaction setup that is giving the error.